# use @Attribute in custom attribute directive and data -binding attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, just a question on use @Attribute in attribute directives, below is some code from a book:

```
@Directive({
 selector: "[pa-attr]",
})
export class PaAttrDirective {
    constructor(element: ElementRef, @Attribute("pa-attr") bgClass: string) {
       element.nativeElement.classList.add(bgClass || "bg-success", "text-white");
 }
}
```

and the template.html:

```
...
<td pa-attr="bg-warning">{{item.category}}</td>
...
```

so we can see that use @Attribute we can get the value of the attribute, but if we use data-binding attribute directive as:

```
<td [pa-attr]="item.category == 'Soccer' ? 'bg-info' : null">...
```

then the book modify the code as:

```
export class PaAttrDirective {
   constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

   @Input("pa-attr")
   bgClass: string;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.element.nativeElement.classList.add(this.bgClass || "bg-success", "text-white");
   }
}
```

I'm a little bit confused here, can't we use @Attribute to get the value again as:

```
export class PaAttrDirective {
    constructor(element: ElementRef, @Attribute("pa-attr") bgClass: string) {
       element.nativeElement.classList.add(bgClass || "bg-success", "text-white");
 }
}
```

why when use the attribute directive with data-binding then we have to create input property in the code and not able to use @Attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use `@Input` instead of `@Attribute` because:

> Attributes initialize DOM properties and then they are done. Property
>   values can change; attribute values can't.

`item.category == 'Soccer' ? 'bg-info' : null` expression changes attribute value, so your Directive wouldn't get the updated value after it was changed.

I suggest to read [about Angular template syntax here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Comment: I get your point, but `pa-attr` is not a true html attribute, and it only get processed by Angular, so can't Angular do sth like get the latest value?

Comment: If you inject it as an attribute with `@Attribute` decorator, Angular assumes it is an attribute. And you can see in [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c7542a1d09b27b027a0367a1f3732a908cdd617a/packages/core/src/di/metadata.ts#L244) it takes input string as a constant

Answer (score 0):

@Attribute: accepts plain primitive types, eg strings and numbers
@Input: accepts anything/an object, eg your own class object

You pass the string `abc` to the attribute like this:

```
<td pa-attr="abc"></td>
```

You pass the same thing to the input like this:

```
<td [pa-attr]="'abc'"></td> <!-- note the single quotes -->
```

Or
in ts

```
x = 'abc';
```

in html

```
<td [pa-attr]="x"></td>
```

I am not sure if you can have a dash in the input property name.